# Positivity of the gaussian convolution at the root

Tags: real-analysis, normal-distribution, convolution

I am currently struggling on the following problem. Let $\sigma>0$ a real number and $g_\sigma$ the gaussian function with mean 0 and deviation $\sigma$. Let also $f$ be a smooth real function such that:

- $f$ is negative before 0
- $f$ is positive after 0
- $f'(0)>0$

We know that it exists a unique $x_\sigma\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $(f*g_\sigma)(x_\sigma)=0$. Can one prove that $(f*g_\sigma)'(x_\sigma)>0$ ?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Did you try to solve it for some $g$, given in explicit form?

Comment: Yes @Botnakov N, if you take $f(x) =ax+b$. The gaussian convolution $f*g_\sigma$ is then equal to $f$. We have the desired result.

Comment: @ Gaetano, linear functions look like degenerate case. It makes sense to try $g(x) = P(x)e^{-a(x-b)^2}$, where $P(x)$ is polynomial and $a, b$ are constants and start with $P(x)$ with small degree.